# Which IDE should I use for Windows 8 Phone development?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am starting to develop apps for Windows 8 Phone. There are three IDEs that I have come across for development purposes:

- VS2012 Professional
- VS2012 Express
- VS 2012 Ultimate

Which IDE should I use, and why?

Comment: There is one difference: Express Edition is free but more limited, Professional is paid but does more.

Comment: Express does not allow you to install Plugins, like ReSharper. And Professional has more features. Express is free, Professional costs money. If you have Professional - use it.

Comment: what about VS 2012 Ultimate?

Comment: @Mayank It's in some way better that Professional, I don't personally need that info because I'm fine with Express for hobby use :)

Comment: I need to drive to work every day.  Which car should I buy?  A VW Golf, a Camry, or a BMW 320i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That decision is a little bit depend from what you want to achieve. If you are a professional and want to earn money with your development, i would recommend the Professional.

If you do this just for fun or are a programming beginner, the Express Edition really is enough. If you get more professional you still can upgrade to the Professional Version at any time. Furthermore Express Edition is for free.

So if you reach the limits of the Express Edition you will notice it, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Professional will let you develop for more all platforms i.e. Phone, Desktop, Store, Web etc, you will be able to use extensions and plugins and it is free.

Visual Studio Express is free but you cannot use extensions and you need one Visual Studio Express for each platform.

Comment: Do you mean that VS 2012 is free ?

Comment: All express editions of VS(2013/2012/2010/2008/2005 etc.) are free and all Professional/Premium/Ultimate editions are paid